# Should I put UIIMageViews directly in the View of the Controller?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiimageview, storyboard

I am writing an app for both IPad and IPhone. I want to put multiple images in the view. I wanted to ask what is a better practice. Should I put multiple views inside the main view and put autolayout constraints on the views and then put UIImageViews taking whole space of subviews? Or,  I should put UIImageViews directly on the main view and put autolayout constraints on the UIImageViews?

What is a better practice?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "one size fits all" answer. Sometimes grouping images inside UIView objects can help give you the layout you want. Other times you might want to animate a group of views together, show/hide them as a group, or some other task where having them grouped inside a view is helpful.

On the other hand, views have some overhead associated with them, so you shouldn't create layers of views that don't serve any purpose.

The rule I would suggest is to put your image views and other views directly inside the view controller's content view unless you have a specific reason to put them inside another view.